# ImageProcessing-Find the center of the circle in a jpeg image by using opencv

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing

I am new at opencv and I am trying to use opencv to find the center of all the disk in this image,and i tried in many method,the result is not so accurate.Here is my code to find the center.I want to find a method to improve the result.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import cv2.cv as cv
imgorg = cv2.imread("keli.jpg")
img = cv2.resize(imgorg,(1024,800),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
x = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_16S,1,0)
y = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_16S,0,1)
cv2.imshow("img",img)
absX = cv2.convertScaleAbs(x)
absY = cv2.convertScaleAbs(y)
sobelresult = cv2.addWeighted(absX,0.5,absY,0.5,0)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3, 3))
opened = cv2.morphologyEx(sobelresult, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(opened, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imshow("Open", opened);
cv2.imshow("Close",closed);
element = cv2.getStructuringElement (cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE ,(3,3))
dilate = cv2.dilate(closed, element)
erode = cv2.erode(closed, element)
result = cv2.absdiff(dilate,erode)
retval, result = cv2.threshold(result, 40, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
result = cv2.bitwise_not(result)
def nothing(x):
    pass
cv2.namedWindow('image')
#hough transform
cv2.createTrackbar('param1','image',1,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('param2','image',1,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('minDistance','image',1,255,nothing)
param1 = cv2.setTrackbarPos('param1','image',55)
param2 = cv2.setTrackbarPos('param2','image',45)
minDistance = cv2.setTrackbarPos('minDistance','image',25)
while(1):
    anotherimg = cv2.imread("keli.jpg")
    anotherimgeresize = cv2.resize(anotherimg,(1024,800),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(result,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    k=cv2.waitKey(0)&0xFF
    if k==27:
        break
    param1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('param1','image')
    param2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('param2','image')
    minDistance = cv2.getTrackbarPos('minDistance','image')
    circles1 = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,
                 minDistance,param1=param1,param2=param2,
                 minRadius=2,maxRadius=80)
    circles = circles1[0,:,:]
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[:]:
        cv2.circle(anotherimgeresize,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(255,0,0),2)
        cv2.circle(anotherimgeresize,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,0),2)
    cv2.imshow('result',anotherimgeresize)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: origin image]

[image]

The param: param1 = 75,param2 =34,minDistance = 25

Comment: post your result images, too, please, for different parameter values.

Comment: @Micka param1=74,param2=34,minDistance =25

Comment: @Micka I just upload a result image.

Comment: "improve result" = remove the false positives? most of them can probably be removed by testing the median/average size of found circles and remove if a circle differs too much. If that is allowed depends on your application. From that one image it looks like as if all the circles should have quite similar size.