# Segmentation of shiny objects touching each other using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I am trying to develop an algorithm to detect and seperate each tomato from a group of them in settings similar to a conveyer. I am focusing on a standing frame. I tried findContour method from openCV but it's not working on tomatoes or similar objects touching each other as can be seen in the image I have provided. I tried distance-transform plus wathershed algorithm next and realized that the shine on the surface is really creating trouble. Can anyone help in making it work ?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def display_image(img, title="Image"):
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.title(title)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()

def create_mask(img):
    saturated = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)[:, :, 1]
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(saturated, (5, 5), 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
    return mask

def apply_watershed(image_path):
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    display_image(img, "Original Image")
    
    thresh = create_mask(img)
    display_image(thresh, "Mask Image")
    
    sure_bg = cv2.dilate(thresh, np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8), iterations=1)
    display_image(sure_bg, "Background Image")

    dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(thresh, cv2.DIST_L2, 5)
    _, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform, 0.7 * dist_transform.max(), 255, 0)
    display_image(sure_fg, "Foreground Image")

    sure_fg = np.uint8(sure_fg)
    unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg, sure_fg)

    _, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_fg)
    markers = markers + 1
    markers[unknown == 255] = 0
    cv2.watershed(img, markers)
    img[markers == -1] = [0, 0, 255]
    display_image(img, "Watershed Image")

    cropped_objects = []
    for label in np.unique(markers):
        if label == 0 or label == 1: 
            continue
        mask = np.zeros(gray.shape, dtype="uint8")
        mask[markers == label] = 255
        cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        for c in cnts:
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            cropped_objects.append(img[y:y+h, x:x+w])

    for i, cropped in enumerate(cropped_objects):
        display_image(cropped, f"Cropped Object {i + 1}")

    return cropped_objects
apply_watershed('T4.jpg')
```

[image]

[image: This is the maksed image. The black spot in one of the object is due to shine.]

[image: This is original image.]

Comment: You could fill the holes in “mask image” before applying the watershed method to it. Seems like a good approach for this particular case. Though it will not work if there are more tomatoes touching each other.

Comment: Unfortunately, there will be different cases where multiple tomatoes might be touching and perhaps not touching at all. I am trying to develop robust algorithm, I would be glad to get more help.

Comment: You could try to subtract an edge-image from your mask-image. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34653138/2393191 as an example